# How can I tell which login is being used to connect to a SQL Server linked server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I can get information about a linked server using the `sp_linked_servers` stored procedure.  What the SP does not give me, however, is login info entered via `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin`.

How can I tell which login is being used to connect to the linked server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.name, s.product, s.data_source, ll.remote_name 
    FROM sys.servers s 
        INNER JOIN sys.linked_logins ll
            ON s.server_id = ll.server_id
    WHERE ll.remote_name IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

my favourite

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer, 'SELECT SUSER_SNAME() AS Who')
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
select s.name, l.remote_name
from sys.linked_logins l
join sys.servers s on s.server_id = l.server_id
```